# Save Uploaded Text File to Web Server

Tags: php

I have my users uploading a text file which then gets processed by my application. Once the processing is done, I would like to save a copy of this text file somewhere on my server for future reference. Currently, the uploaded text file stays in the PHP temp folder until it is closed by my app.

What's a simple way to accomplish this?

BTW, I'll need to know how to do this on my web server along with localhost (for testing).

Comment: [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php), maybe?

Comment: I'm trying to test this on localhost right now, any examples/suggestions on how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **fwrite** function (this is probably not a very good idea in this particular example though.

```
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $yourContents);
fclose($fp);
```

But, if you already have the file simply copy it using the copy command (if you want to keep it in the temp folder that is, if not move it with the rename function instead).

To **copy**, do something like this

```
$tempfile = 'tempfile.txt';
$newfile = 'newfile.txt';

if (copy($tempfile, $newfile)) {
    echo "success!";
} else {
    echo "misery :(";
}
```

To move with **rename**

```
// Rename returns a bool, just as in the copy example
rename("/tmp/tempfile.txt", "/home/user/files/newfile.txt");
```

**Added this:** To move with **move_uploaded_file**

*Please note, I didn't test this in a development environment. This may not execute perfectly.*

```
$uploads_dir = 'C:\\movefiles\\here\\';
foreach ($_FILES["upload-tracking-file"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["upload-tracking-file"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["upload-tracking-file"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir\\$name");
    }
}
```

**References**

- Copy, http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php
- Move (rename), http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php
- move_uploaded_file, http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php
- fwrite, http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to use the `rename` function (testing on localhost right now) and it looks like when stepping through my code, that this is the location/name of the uploaded text file before I perform the move: `C:\wamp\tmp\php96E1.tmp`. As you can see, it doesn't look like it has a `.txt` extension initially. I got that info by doing: `$varStoredIn = $_FILES["upload-tracking-file"]["tmp_name"];` Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you want to move it like that you should use the move_uploaded_file as suggested by Adnan, I'll extend my example.

Answer (score 0):

use php's function ob_start(), and file_put_contents() this should help you. this links will help you if not post your reply
 php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php,  php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php